# Experimental proof of the benefit of regularization?

Tags: regression, svm, regularization, overfitting

Did somebody prove experimentally that linear regression with regularization is better for prediction than the same type of regression without regularization? I would be particularly interested to know if somebody did these real data experiments with linear SVM with and without regularization (the $w^2$ part).

I can find neither experimental, nor theoretical proof.

My suspicion is that overfitting of linear regression may be caused by over-counting outliers, rather than by the flatness of the slop of the regression. Did somebody prove me wrong?

Comment: Search for any tutorial on regularisation. The typical example is polynomial regression with Gaussian noise

Comment: @seanv507 The question was: (1) experimental proof of benefit of regularization of (2) linear regression, and (3) linear SVM in particular.

Comment: Polynomial regression is linear regression with inputs that happen to be nonlinear functions of other inputs

Comment: seanv507 I am asking about linear regression which is just linear on the features.   I want to see an "experimental proof".   Thanks.